# Silverlight 4 Error using WCF services to return Generic List items c#

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I am getting the below error when trying to access a WCF Silverlight enabled service hosted in a standard way in a web app. I am trying to return a List of type `<ER_Theme>` to the Silverlight app.

This is the Services.References.ClientConfig generated in the Silveright app:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_ER">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000" maxBufferSize="1000000000" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:52377/ER.svc" binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ER" contract="ERService.ER"
                name="CustomBinding_ER" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The actual Service code is as follows:

```
 [OperationContract]
        public List<ER_Theme> GetThemes()
        {
            // Add your operation implementation here
            using (Client_BespokeEntities myDB = new Client_BespokeEntities())
            {
                List<ER_Theme> myThemes;
                myThemes = (from p in myDB.ER_Themes
                            select p).ToList();
                return myThemes;
            }
        }
```

This is the WebConfig settings in the Web App:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="SilverlightTool.Web.ER.customBinding0">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SilverlightTool.Web.SilverlightServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="SilverlightTool.Web.ER">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TMPSilverlightTool.Web.ER.customBinding0" contract="SilverlightTool.Web.ER" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
{System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)}
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: To get more info, try adding the following to your main window Xaml code behind (after the InitializeComponent call):            WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but the error message I get is the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague has just assisted in this and has found that if you disable Lazy Loading in your entity framework model then this will solve the issue. Thanks for the suggestions guys.

Comment: how do you disable lazy loading Kevin? I just remember, I had problem like that in the past...

Comment: Its just a property on the EF database model within your project, just disable it here.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, may be you have another error in code? try to debug your service method, Silverlight shows not found error in any exception from the server.

Comment: The collection in the service method successully returns a List<ER_Theme> with a count of 6, so I know this aspect of it works.